# confirm which dataset is closer to benchmark

Tags: statistical-significance, cross-validation, dataset

I have 3 datasets of different sizes and trying to select one that is the closest to the benchmark, in a sense of minimized pairwise differences.  I checked for normality using QQ plots and Shapiro-Wilk test and the datasets are nto normal.  Here is their descriptive summary:

```
          benchmark   B          R           P
count  612.000000  618.000000  126.000000  270.000000
mean    89.050933   88.211827   88.795638   88.790035
std      9.266400    9.643709    9.536293    8.299144
min     54.806048   53.240000   61.672506   61.262190
25%     82.750140   81.296000   83.342725   82.811940
50%     90.934203   90.622500   89.901740   91.287030
75%     96.057921   95.487000   95.149459   95.304870
max    115.683067  125.602000  109.569155  101.482260
```

From the attached kde plot, it appears that it's either "B" or "P" set, but how to statistically test which is the closest?  I'm thinking of minimizing  of the of difference metrics in [distance metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html#metrics)
[image: kde_plot]

Comment: This question already has an answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52471839/measure-difference-between-two-distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52471839/measure-difference-between-two-distribution)

Comment: It depends on what is the definition of “closer” that you care about. E.g. if you mostly care about having similar averages, use this as a criterion. Also, why do you need to pick it? Can't you use all the datasets?

Comment: @Tim, Thanks I updated the question.  can only pick one as they all cost $.